# What happens to an iOS deeplink when the app is not installed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

From this Facebook diagram, if the user does not have the app installed, they will be prompted to install it in iTunes. What happens after that?

[image: Deep link]
<sub>(source: [facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/ios-app-flow.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing.  The user will have to restart the flow from the beginning.